# assigning onmouseover event to my htmldocument is not working

Tags: c#, ihtmldocument2

I'm working on a project in which I'm writing a c# **windows application** that wants to get the current element under the cursor from a running instance of Internet Explorer.

I can get the handle of IHtmlDocument2 of the running instance of IE and I want to assign it the onmouseover event like this:

```
 DHTMLEventHandler myHandler = new DHTMLEventHandler(htmlDocument);
 myHandler.Handler += new DHTMLEvent(this.BrowserEventHandler);
 htmlDocument.onmouseover = myHandler;
```

And because I didn't want the IE to eat other events (a famous but solved question), I should create a DHTMLEventHandler class like this:

```
public delegate void DHTMLEvent(IHTMLEventObj obj);

[ComVisible(true)]
public class DHTMLEventHandler
{
    public DHTMLEvent Handler;

    private IHTMLDocument2 Document;

    public DHTMLEventHandler(IHTMLDocument2 doc)
    {
        Document = doc;
    }

    [DispId(0)]
    public void Call()
    {
        Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);
    }
}
```

And my BrowserEventHandler method is like this:

```
public void BrowserEventHandler(IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
    }
```

Still empty (but I want to get the element’s `innerHtml`  under cursor), but still this method is empty and I get :

**A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in FindText.exe**

Whenever I move the mouse.

**Questions:**

1. Why I'm getting this exception?
2. Is it possible to get e.srcElement.innerhtml in a variable and use in my c# application?

Let me know if there's something unclear and ambiguous. Thanks in advance for any help and ideas. I *greatly* appreciate any comments and helps.

**Update:**

To answer my second question, it seems possible to get the `e.srcElement.innerHTML` of the `IHTMLEventObj e` but I really don't know why the `BrowserEventHandler` method is never called. Any ideas or hints?

**update2:**

Ok, I found the problem. First I changed some settings of my project to get the line where the exception occurs first (since it's a first chance exception) like this:

In visual studio: Menu >> Debug >> Exceptions >> CLR exceptions >> system and check the throw option of SystemInvalidCastException.

I found the problem is with this line of `DHTMLEventHandler` class:

```
Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);
```

It throws `Invalid Cast Exception` which I think is related to `Thread`s according to my recent searches.

I guess I should set ApartmentState to `ApartmentState.STA`. But I don't know how. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,I found the solution! :)

I needed to change `DHTMLEventHandler` class like this:

```
public delegate void DHTMLEvent(IHTMLEventObj obj);

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class DHTMLEventHandler
{
    private Thread currentThread;
    public DHTMLEvent Handler;

    private IHTMLDocument2 Document;

    public DHTMLEventHandler(IHTMLDocument2 doc)
    {
        Document = doc;
    }

    [DispId(0)]
     [STAThread]
    public void Call()
    {
        currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
       Thread parentWin = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pWindowHandler));
        parentWin.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        parentWin.Start();
        currentThread.Suspend();
       // Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);

    }
    public void pWindowHandler()
    {
        Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);
        currentThread.Resume();
    }
}
```

But if anybody else tries to use my solution, I don't know whether It has any side effects in other situations. At least it works fine for me! :)

Comment: Thank you Luke for posting an answer. I am trying to get this to work in VB.NET and am having all kinds of problems.  The thread that is used in Call is an MTA thread so useless to VB.NET. I surprised it works in C#. But I have this set up while automating IE at the same time and if the event fires as a result of my code elsewhere everything locks up. I tried your code as well and stopped the Call thread, but this is the thread of IE so nothing can be done.

Answer (score 0):

For setting Apartment use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx

Comment: Thank you for posting the link (It has some good points which I never cared about before). But for my problem, I created a new thread in the `call` method and then set the ApartmentState to `ApartmentState.STA`. When I did this the exception disappeared but for `IHTMLEventObj e` in `BrowserEventHandler` I get null (the e is null). I guess I'm making a mistake in threads, any idea? (Thanks again for the link) :)